# How can different domain sellers sell the same domain?

Tags: domain

When I go to two different sites that both offer domains I can buy the same domain at both websites. Doesn't that mean they both own the same domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The domain registrars do *not* own all of the domain names they are selling. They are accredited by either global our country domain registry to provide domain names to particulars.

Basically this means that until a domain name is registered for the first time it does not belong to anybody. Once it registration expires it returns to the pool as well.

For further reading on [Domain name registrars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_registrar)

Comment: Does this mean that the prices can vary drastically when it does not belong to anybody since any domain registrar can own it?